# Hi, I am unable to make this code work as it is saying "not all code paths return a value." I am not sure what is not working here

Tags: compiler-errors

```
using System;

namespace code1
{
    class Program
    {
        static object main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("What's your name?");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine($"Hello {input}!");
            /* This part will tell the user their age in a string */
            Console.WriteLine("How old are you?");
            double age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine($"You are {age} years old");
            Console.WriteLine("Next Part....");
            Console.WriteLine("Next.");


        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Why is `main`s return type `object`?

Answer (score 1):

You have a wrong return type for the function main. It should return nothing = void.

```
using System;

namespace code1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("What's your name?");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine($"Hello {input}!");
            /* This part will tell the user their age in a string */
            Console.WriteLine("How old are you?");
            double age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine($"You are {age} years old");
            Console.WriteLine("Next Part....");
            Console.WriteLine("Next.");


        }
    }
    
}
```

**Edit 2:**
You should also be **consistent with datatypes**. You are defining **age as double** but converting the **user input to Int32**. **Either** use `Convert.ToDouble()` **or** change variable declaration to `int` (or `var` to use inference).

Answer (score 0):

Type return of method is Object, but you don't return anything.
static object main()

Edit:
static void main()